# Python Preproccessing for Tesseract OCR

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library, tesseract

The overall goal is to preproccess a .PNG file before it is given to Tesseract for OCR. This code is designed to blur and set a threshold on the image.

The error I am receiving from the Python 2.7.13 shell states:

```
usage: preproccess.py [-h] -i IMAGE [-p PREPROCESS]
preproccess.py: error: argument -i/--image is required
```

What did I miss concerning variables?

--image : The path to the image we’re sending through the OCR system.

--preprocess : The preprocessing method. This switch is optional and for this code can accept two values: thresh (threshold) or blur. (Did I get this part right? Line 12)

```
# import the necessary packages from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
import argparse
import cv2
import os

# construct the argument parse and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required=True,
    help="C:\Automation\OCR\images\Capture.PNG")
ap.add_argument("-p", "--preprocess", type=str, default="thresh, blur",
    help="thresh, blur") # LINE 12
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

# load the example image and convert it to grayscale
image = cv2.imread(args["image"])
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

cv2.imshow("image", gray)

# check to see if we should apply thresholding to preprocess the image
if args["preprocess"] == "thresh":
    gray = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255,
        cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# make a check to see if median blurring should be done to remove noise
elif args["preprocess"] == "blur":
    gray = cv2.medianBlur(gray, 3)

# write the grayscale image to disk as a temporary file so we can apply OCR to it
filename = "Capture.PNG".format(os.getpid())
cv2.imwrite(filename, gray)

# load the image as a PIL/Pillow image, apply OCR, and then delete the temporary file
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(filename))
os.remove(filename)
print(text)

# show the output images
cv2.imshow("image", image)
cv2.imshow("Output", gray)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: how are you executing the script?

Comment: @MuhammadAbdullah running the module on IDLE Python GUI, the Python version I am using is 2.7.13.